# Print Django ForeignKey object text in html?

Tags: python, html, django

I have these Django models:

```
class Message(models.Model): 
    subject = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=10000, blank=True)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(
                    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                    null = True, 
                    related_name="sender"
                    )

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=140,blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=True,null=True)
```

I passed the model into my html and javascript files (name is received), and I want to retrieve each field. For the subject and text fields, I did:

```
var subject = received.fields.subject;  // outputs correct data
var text = received.fields.text;        // outputs correct data
```

However, when I do the same thing for the foreignKeyModels in order to get the username of the sender:

```
var firstname = received.fields.sender.first_name // returns integers(?)
```

I get integer outputs like 17, 20, etc.. I think each of these corresponds to a single user. How do I retrieve the textfields from the User model (ForeignKey) through the received model I imported?

EDIT:

In views.py, I added this to my context dictionary:

```
received = serializers.serialize('json',Message.objects.filter(receiver=user))
```

In my html file, I passed received into a function like

```
onclick="myFunction({{received}})"
```

In myFunction(received), I am trying to change innerHTML (I can't do this within the HTML file for my purposes)

Comment: *How* did you pass the model to your HTML?

Comment: How did you fetch the object into `received`?

Comment: @ubadub check my edit

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem check my edit

Comment: Have you tried printing out the message object to see what is actually being passed? Try doing so both on the Python side and on the JS side.